# Accessing Azure Tables from within a virtual network

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Is there any way to access an azure table using the API from within a virtual network? The storage account was created pre-virtual network. Currently, the code works fine (a test worker role) that creates a table, but fails when I place it inside a virtual network.

It's not possible to report on the exception being thrown as nothing is shown in diagnostics

```
         CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("test");
         bool retVal = table.CreateIfNotExists();
```

Thanks

Comment: make sure you have the right connection strings for the diagnostics. it's usually set to the local storage emulator.

Comment: it works fine when running outside of the vnet. The connection string does point to the correct storage account

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how you're creating your table client, but Table Storage access, via REST calls (or through SDKs which then make REST calls) is done directly to the storage account, which *cannot* be added to a virtual network.

All storage calls will work, whether you're making those calls from an on-premises app, an app in a non-vnet VM/cloud service/web app/mobile app, or something within a vnet.

Comment: I'm creating it from the CloudStorageAccount that I get from parsing my connection key.

The deployment shows itself as having correctly loaded,  with the instance running, but then nothing happens. No data gets sent to the diagnostics tables (it does when outside the vnet), and the table above never gets created.

Comment: I doubt this has something to do with the vnet like David Makogon stated above.  Have you stepped thru the code in the debug mode?  What was the exact error message?

Comment: The code works fine when removing the configuration option for the vnet, and no longer works when adding the configuration option for the vnet. That's what is leading me to point to the vnet. (When running in dbug mode with the storage emulator, also works fine)