# Azure Storage and VNET?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-network

I've been scouring the internet to try to find information on how Azure Storage and Azure Virtual Networks work together, is it possible to setup a Storage so that it can be accessed from another location?

For example I have a centralized authentication solution hosted on the US EAST center, but I have several identical region-local systems (one on EU NORTH, EU WEST, US EAST and US WEST) that need to be able to authenticate its users against the centralized authenticator located on the US EAST data-center.

Comment: This should be on ServerFault.

Comment: Further, this has been answered in other questions, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677578/accessing-azure-tables-from-within-a-virtual-network).

Answer (score 2):

Storage is not accessed via virtual networks. It's is accessed via its URI endpoint directly. You just access it from your app. If you cross region boundaries (e.g. running an app in one region, accessing storage in another region), you have to deal with latency, plus the cost of any outbound storage cost (for any data leaving the region).

Comment: This has now been partly changed, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security. Could you please update your answer based on this?